# Warning: Failed propType: transitionAppearTimeout wasn't supplied to ReactCSSTransitionGroup (React.js)

Tags: animation, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

My code works fine but I am getting this annoying error.  What is the issue?

> Warning: Failed propType: transitionAppearTimeout wasn't supplied to ReactCSSTransitionGroup: this can cause unreliable animations and won't be supported in a future version of React. See [fb.me/react-animation-transition-group-timeout](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#getting-started) for more information. Check the render method of `SocialIcons`.

```
render: function() {

        return (

        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true}>
                <div className="small_caps" key="small_caps">
                    <a href="mailto:******" key="email" id="email" target="_blank"><i className="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i></a>

                </div>
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>

        );

var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says that since you have enabled transition to appear on initial mount using

> transitionAppear={true}

You need to provide a value for the timeout transitionAppearTimeout. This is enforced through the component specification.

try providing a value for timeout for the animation using this property explicitly as in the fb documentation.

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true} transitionAppearTimeout={500}>
```